# Is this figure a correct representation of off-policy actor-critic methods?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods, off-policy-methods

[image: on-policy (left) vs. off-policy (right) actor critic]

Does this figure correctly represent the overall general idea about actor-critic methods for on-policy (left) and off-policy (right) case?

I am a bit confused about the off-policy case (right figure). Why does the right figure represent the off-policy actor-critic methods?